# Allow ads on all sites except selected once in google chrome AdBlock extension

Tags: adblock

I am trying out the [AdBlock extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-%E2%80%94-best-ad-blocker/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom) in Google Chrome on Windows 10.

Is there a way to allow all ads everywhere, except specific websites? What I want to have happen is, I want all sites to open normally as if there was no AdBlock installed, but for specific sites I add to a blacklist I want all ads blocked. I think I had done something similar on a different computer many months ago, but I recently installed AdBlock on a new computer and can’t seem to find the option.

Is it possible to block ads in AdBlock in this manner?

Or is there another popular/reliable adblocker that does this? I just need it to work on Google Chrome in Windows 10.

FWIW, I tried the ideas suggested in [this “How to…” blog post](https://www.howtogeek.com/344726/how-to-set-adblock-to-only-block-ads-on-specific-sites/) but it didn’t work.

This is the sample website I tried it on: https://mynewmicrophone.com/what-is-the-difference-between-sound-and-audio/

Enabling AdBlock across all websites removes the Google ads at the right and bottom of this page, but the method suggested in the "How to..." tutorial linked above does not make the ads disappear.